# Multiple options in the options_value field of the wp_options table

Tags: theme-options, options

I have come across a theme that has a way of having multiple options in the option_value field.For instance,in the theme,one can perform the Create,Read,Uodate and Delete functionalities on such fields as

-image url

-link url

-description

The wp_options has the following fields:

> option_id / blog_id / option_name / option_value / autoload

How is this being done?.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to do that. This is how to Consolidate Options with Arrays described in this article

http://striderweb.com/nerdaphernalia/2008/07/consolidate-options-with-arrays/

Related question: [How do you store options with a:n:{{}} syntax in wp_options?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6451/how-do-you-store-options-with-an-syntax-in-wp-options)